# mysql select query php based on column value

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table like this,

[image]

i want to select all doc no having status 1.
`select * from tbl where doc_status=1` will select **101,102,101**. But in for **doc_no 101** there is doc-status 0 also so it wont select.How can i do that, desired output will be
**103 only**

Comment: plz try this. select * from tbl where doc_status='1'  what is data type of doc_status

Comment: Select x.* from my_table x left join my_table y on y.doc_no = x.doc_no and y.status <> 1 where x.status = 1 and y.id is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM test GROUP BY doc_no HAVING MIN(doc_status) = 1;
```

[SQL Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f1dde/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT T.doc_no
FROM tbl T
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
 SELECT 
 1
 FROM tbl TT
 WHERE TT.doc_status = 0
 AND TT.doc_no = T.doc_no
)
```

<kbd>[**Working Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/720dc/1/0)</kbd>

**Note:** I guess `doc_status` can hold value either `0/1`. If this is the case then no need to filter with `doc_status = 1` outside.

**OR** you can use `NOT IN`

```
SELECT 
 DISTINCT T.doc_no
FROM tbl T
WHERE T.doc_no NOT IN
(
 SELECT 
    TT.doc_no
 FROM tbl TT
 WHERE TT.doc_status = 0
)
```